# Magento 2: How to get certification of Magento 2 Frontend?

Tags: magento2, associatedevelopercertification

Anyone used to get certification of Magento 2.

May you show me how to get certification of Magento 2 FrontEnd ?

How the exam will happen, do we need a personal computer with webcam ?

And apart from documentation do we have any document and mock exam to take off in current updated?

Any help will be appreciated THanks.

Comment: If you give exam from test center. Then, you don't pc with webcam. otherwise, you need laptop/pc with webcam.

Comment: https://www.integer-net.com/the-magento-2-online-certification-how-it-works/